# My 4GB USB drive has decided that it should be 2GB

Tags: formatting, usb-storage

Uh. I looked at the properties on windows, it says that its formatted as RAW, and 0 bytes. When I try to format, no matter what filesystem I use, I can only format to 1.92 GB. I have tried on 2 windows 7 machines and an XP, I'll try Ubuntu or Fedora when I get home if that might work.

Comment: Have you ever actually had this device formatted to 4gb, or is it new?

Comment: Have you tried *partitioning* the drive?

Comment: Is it possible that you bought a cheap knock-off that is really only 2GB or had a hardware failure?

Comment: Mind telling us the brand name of the drive?  (Might find interesting: http://thegadgetsite.com/2011/04/fake-samsung-hdd-appears-chinese-scammers-seem-to-have-found-the-trick-to-build-an-infinite-hard-drive/)

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell without more information, but the most likely answer is that your drive really *is* a 2GB drive. Some unscrupulous people sell devices with a faked capacity.

The drives are doctored to report a higher capacity than they really have. Sometimes this is accomplished by manipulating the filesystem structures on the device, then reformatting such a device will show the true capacity, because it corrects the doctored filesystem structures.

See e.g. this link for some explanations: [BurnInTest FAQ - Testing for fake counterfeit USB drive capacity](http://www.passmark.com/support/bit_fake_USB_detection.htm) .

Answer (score 0):

Are you [using a 32-bit system](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/dude-wheres-my-4-gigabytes-of-ram.html)?

Comment: That is only applicable to memory, as 32-bit memory addresses run out. The OP is referring to a USB pen drive, which serves as a removable storage device.